# Get image ByteArray from onActivityResult to oncreate

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onactivityresult

I have global variable **byte[] byteArr;** which i want to save value of bytearray when image is clicked and set the value after **TakeImage(img_view);** method in **ed[finalI].setText(bytearray);**
This below code is above onCreate

```
private Bitmap global_bitmap;
```

This below code is in **onCreate** from which when i click it popups the option to select gallery

```
final XEditText ed[] = new XEditText[arraylist.size()];
final XImageView xImageViews[] = new XImageView[arraylist.size()];



    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
  ed[i] = new XEditText(this);
  xImageViews[i] = new XImageView(this);

ed[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

TakeImage(img_view);
xImageViews[finalI1].setImageBitmap(global_bitmap);
ed[finalI1].setText(global_bitmap.toString());

}
  });


}
```

This the method i am calling from oncreate

```
public void TakeImage(final ImageView imageview) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builderimage = new AlertDialog.Builder(JSON_Form_Activity.this);
        builderimage.setTitle("Choose Image");
        builderimage.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });



        builderimage.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });


        builderimage.show();

    }
```

After this there are methods for onActivityResult like below

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                img_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byteArr = stream.toByteArray();

                Path_Image_model path_image_model = new Path_Image_model();
                path_image_model.setPath(byteArr.toString());

                Log.d(TAG, "===byteArr_PickImage==" + byteArr);
                img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                  global_bitmap=bitmap;


                resizedFile = new File(uri.getPath()); 
                Log.d(TAG, "===FileImage==" + resizedFile);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
```

On the first go it shows me null value and on second go its shows one previous value i want real global_bitmap value of selected imageview from Gallery on every img_btn.setOnClickListener click

Comment: ` ed[finalI].setText(bytearray);` will be inside `onActivityResult()`

Comment: @TejasPandya i am creatin dynamic edittext in  oncreate

Comment: 1) that wont be the problem, if you are creating edittext runtime or in xml . 2) I'm confuse with **settext of bytearray in edittext** . What you really wanna do ?

Comment: @TejasPandya i want to get the bytearray or lets say path of selected image from gallery to edittext

Comment: so you want to set path of the image in edittext ?

Comment: @TejasPandya yes correct

Comment: in  `Log.d(TAG, "===FileImage==" + resizedFile);` are you getting real path for image ?

Comment: @TejasPandya yes getting but that i am passing that value after onActivityResult to global and then but on click i am getting null value then after i am getting previous value

Comment: move your  `ed[finalI].setText(bytearray);`  inside onActivityResult() and see whats happening

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'finalI' and Cannot resolve symbol 'ed'

Comment: you have to declare your `int finalI` and `edittext ed`  public above onCreate

Comment: @TejasPandya sorry for delay i have updated the code above....your case works for single edittext but how to do in multiple case of edittext ..i am showing imageview and then edittext with value of global_bitmap from onActivityResult to edittext

Comment: @TejasPandya any help ?

Comment: if you have mulitple edittext  like edttext1,edittext2...edittextn  then you can set value of each edittext in for loop also . for all edittext

Comment: @TejasPandya could you please elaborate according to code i updated the code

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResultMethod:

```
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    img_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byteArr = stream.toByteArray();

                    Path_Image_model path_image_model = new Path_Image_model();
                    path_image_model.setPath(byteArr.toString());

                    Log.d(TAG, "===byteArr_PickImage==" + byteArr);
                    img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    ed[finalI].setText(byteArr);

                    resizedFile = new File(uri.getPath()); 
                    Log.d(TAG, "===FileImage==" + resizedFile);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Please update you onActivityResultMethod